# Appbar on Pivot in Windows Phone 8.1 with Caliburn

Tags: c#, xaml, caliburn.micro, windows-phone-8.1, appbar

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 project, where the main view is a pivot. The app has an applicationbar, which shows different items, depending on which pivotitem the user currently is. I also use the caliburn.micro 2 framework.

My problem is that I cannot change the AppBar when the user changes the current pivotitem.

I had different approaches to solve this problem:

- In WP8 i could set the "BindableAppBar" in the different PivotViews. With the AppBarConductor it was easy to manage this problem. But for WP8.1 the BindableAppBar is not available and I cannot find a built in AppBarConductor.
- It seems not possible to create the AppBar in the code behind, because then i cannot use other caliburn conventions (such as x:Name="Reload" --> calls Reload-Method in the ViewModel)
- Google a lot

Hope there is a better answer somewhere than "use the same AppBar in all pivotitems"...:-)

Answer (score 0):

non-silverlight application (there is a huge difference)? BindableAppBar is a separate project not part of the assemblies for Caliburn.Micro.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thunbrynt/archive/2014/04/09/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-application-bar.aspx, you might need to do things differently now that application bar is completely bindable! since it is based off the Win8 bars.  You should still be able to move your pivot change event to viewmodel now.

Comment: Non-silverlight. Yes, I know, but it doesn't seem to work in a Windows Runtime Project. I managed it now, by showing and hidding the different buttons on Pivot_SelectionChanged in code behind. Not very nice, but works the best until now :-)